# Usar variable booleana con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Amigos, esta es mi primera pregunta. Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual necesito agrandar y achicar un elemento usando Jquery. Mi profesor sugirió usar una variable booleana para usar el mismo boton para achicar y agrandar. Traté de desarrollar la animación y en los dos primeros click, lo logro y luego se agranda y se achica sola. Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="boton" class="btn" style="background-color: red; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">
          <span>haz click!!!</span>
        </div>
        <div id="cambio" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">
          <span>Cambiame</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    // 1. Al hacer click sobre la caja que dice "haz click", aumenta el tamaño y el color de la
    // caja que dice "cambiame" (sólo utiliza jQuery). Siente la libertad de agregar las
    // clases o ids que sean necesarios (no modificar estructura html entregada).
var primer = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#boton").on("click", function () {
      $("#boton > span").css("color", "white");
      $("#cambio").css("background", "blue").css("color", "white");
          if (primer) {
                  $("#cambio").animate({
                    height: "200px",
                  });
          }
          primer = false
          if (!primer){
            $("#boton").on("click", function () {
              primer = true
                  $("#cambio").animate({
                        height: "10px",
                  });
            });
          }
    });
});

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Esta respuesta me sirve, y pude entender como usar la variable booleana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas, que son los que te están provocando ese comportamiento indeseado.

1. Las condiciones están mal montadas. Si `primer` es `true`, después de entrar por él, se cambia a `false` y también entra por el `false`. Cosa que no te interesa, lo interesante es que entre por una o por la otra, nunca por ambas.
2. En el `false` vuelves a vincular un evento **click** al botón. Por lo que en el mismo momento en que entras por `false` tu botón lanza ambas animaciones, tanto la de abrirse, como la de cerrarse cada vez que lo pulsas.

Mi solución pasa por construir un `if()` y un `else()` para que nunca se puedan cumplir las dos condiciones y también por quitar el segundo evento **click**. No parece necesario.

```js
$(function () {
  var primer = true;

  $("#boton").on("click", function () {
      $("#boton > span").css("color", "white");
      $("#cambio").css("background", "blue").css("color", "white");
      
      if (primer) {
        $("#cambio").animate({
          height: "200px",
        });
        primer = false
      }
      else {
        $("#cambio").animate({
          height: "10px",
        });
        primer = true
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="boton" class="btn" style="background-color: red; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">
          <span>haz click!!!</span>
        </div>
        <div id="cambio" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">
          <span>Cambiame</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```